# How to set min and max number of tags on Materialize CSS tag input

Tags: material-design, materialize

Are there options (for instance) that can be added to `material_chip` to make it possible? (The official docs doesn't specify whether or how to accomplish this). If not, what work around can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chip.add` and `chip.delete` events to disable possibility of adding new tag and enable again when user removes any tag. For example:

```
$('.chips').on('chip.add', function(e, chip){
    // Check current number of tags/chips - disable if need
});

$('.chips').on('chip.delete', function(e, chip){
    // Enable again
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems Materialize doesn't expose any methods to programmatically add or delete tags/pills. I intend to do max by deleting any tag added after a max number (e.g 5) I set i.e if tagsCount > 5 delete just added tag. Is that the method you're suggesting for max? If yes how do I make it work. I can do the validation for min.

Answer (score 0):

For those who faced the same problem and want a quick solution Here is a small example to determine the maximum tags

```
var chipCounter =0;
    $('.chips').on('chip.add', function(e, chip){
        chipCounter++;
        if (chipCounter >= 5){
            console.log('5 max');

            $('.chips > .input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.chips-placeholder').materialChip({
                placeholder: 'You have 5 tags maximum ',
            });

        }

    });
    $('.chips').on('chip.delete', function(e, chip){

        chipCounter--;
        if (chipCounter < 5){
            $('.chips-placeholder').materialChip({
                placeholder: 'Enter a Tag ',
            });
            $('.chips > .input').removeAttr('disabled')
        }
    });
```